# Filtering Project explorer context menu

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have different kind of projects in the eclipse project explorer, say a normal Java project and custom project. I have menu contributions for custom project. On right click of the custom project I want to display the project related menus only, right now its showing all the menu options. I tried with removing menus by attaching  IMenuListener but I don't think its the proper way. Using activities seems to be good one but I am not getting how to use it for filtering menus on context base :
This how I removing unwanted menus , I have attached this listener into the IMenumanager. But on first right click all the menus are appearing

```java
  private final class MenuListener implements IMenuListener2
  {
    @Override
    public void menuAboutToShow(IMenuManager manager)
    {
      ISelection selection = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService().getSelection(IPageLayout.ID_PROJECT_EXPLORER);
      if (selection != null && !selection.isEmpty())
      {
        if (selection instanceof IStructuredSelection)
        {
          Object obj = ((IStructuredSelection) selection).getFirstElement();

          if (applContainerPorjectNatureChecker.apply(obj))
          {
            IContributionItem[] items = manager.getItems();
            for (IContributionItem item : items)
            {
              if (ids.contains(item.getId()))
              {
                item.setVisible(false);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void menuAboutToHide(IMenuManager manager)
    {
      // TODO:Do Nothing
    }
  }
```

Comment: added a code snippet

Comment: I think this is really hard (if it can be done at all).

Comment: Menus are disappearing only after second right click but not on the first one, I don't know why :(

Answer (score 0):

In method menuAboutToShow

```
public void menuAboutToShow(IMenuManager manager) {
    // Get the selection object
    // if selectedObj instanceof CustumProject {
         // get the list of customProject actions which you want to add
         // Add it like below:
         for (Action action : actionList)
             menuManager.add(action(action.getId()));
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yes I am doing same, but all menus are enabled on first right click in other words no changes happening on first right click :(